# How to solve this syntax error of gawk (GNU awk) on OSX terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, osx

I'm using OSX terminal and trying to extract specified text of log file by regex.

awk version is

```
GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2018 Free Software Foundation.
```

my trying operation is

```
$gawk '/123/ BEGIN{RS="DEBUG"; FS="\n"}{print $0"\n"}END{}' ./app_108_utf8_T2.log > output.txt
```

but awk says

```
gawk: cmd. line:1: /123/ BEGIN{RS="DEBUG"; FS="\n"}{print $0"\n"}END{}
gawk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error
```

Why does awk say error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m guessing you want to run

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="DEBUG"; FS="\n"} /123/{print $0"\n"}' ./app_108_utf8_T2.log > output.txt
```

`BEGIN` defines the block of instructions which run at the start of the process, and `/123/` defines the block which runs when the “123” regular expression matches the current line. You can’t specify both for a single block.

Comment: Tangentially related: You also can't use e.g. `condition && END {...}`, which is a pity sometimes.

Comment: @user74176 If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).